# Возможно ли на чистом css реализовать меню, которыое адаптируется под разные количества пунктов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, есть задача сверстать меню, которое меняет свой вид в зависимости от количества пунктов в нем: http://prntscr.com/j6v6mn

Есть ли варианты сверстать без применения js? Количество пунктов меню можно опреелить с сервера и задать определенный класс списку, если больше определенного числа пунктов меню, но это может быть не совсем практично, ведь пункты могут быть разными по размеру.

Если всетаки нету варианта без js, возможно посоветуете как?

Очень благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.е вам нужно что бы при любом кол-ве пунктов умещалось все в 1 строку? или элементы должны прятаться или смещаться если не подходят по размеру?

То, что на скрине можно через flex сделать.
списку ul даешь display:flex; flex-direction:row; justify-content: flex-start; и должно получиться что-то похожее.

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо большое